# Centering a div fed by dynamic content

Tags: html, css

So, I have this:

```
<div>
<img src="img1.jpg">
<img src="img2.jpg">
<img src="img3.jpg">
</div>
```

I want this to be centered horizontally with the browser window, even if I insert more images into the div. (So, no fixed width div size)
The solution I found was `div{text-align: center;}`, but that doesn't seem to be right, as img tags aren't text.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: no, that should be right. If you're feeling adventurous, play with margins- img{left:50%;margin-left:-x} where -x = half the img width, negative.

Comment: else center the div. use `div{margin: 0 auto;}`

Comment: `div{text-align: center;}` centers the images by far...

Comment: `text-align` affects all elements that are `display: inline` (text) and `display: block` (images by default), amonst other things. So unless you do something like `display: block; float: left` to the images this should work perfectly fine.

Comment: @MildlySerious img is display:inline-block by default. Only in this case it will be treated as *inline* block - in the same way as single glyph of text.

Comment: @c-smile You are right of course! I meant to write `inline-block` (otherwise saying they are affected by `text-align` doesn't make any sense either).

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML to something like:

```
 <div class="container">
     <img src="img1.jpg">
     <img src="img2.jpg">
     <img src="img1.jpg">
 </div>
```

Then add in your CSS:

```
.container {
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

This will move the whole container in the center of the site.